# Dplyr cumsum with constraining column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a problem where the I have a quantity of units that need to be produced but there are capacity restrictions.
So I have a data frame, two columns, one for capacity I can build, each row is a week and an allocation column, which is how much gets used up by the deal.
The allocation can't be larger than the capacity.

See below where the deal amount is 10.

```
df <- data.frame(capacity = c(2,3,0,1,2,3),
                     allocation = c(0,0,0,0,0,0))

capacity allocation
       2          0
       3          0
       0          0
       1          0
       2          0
       3          0

amount <- 10

dfb <- data.frame(capacity = c(2,3,0,1,2,3),
                      allocation = c(2,3,0,1,2,2))
```

And this is the result I want

```
capacity allocation
       2          2
       3          3
       0          0
       1          1
       2          2
       3          2
```

I tried the following but it's not giving me the correct answer

```
dfb <- df %>% 
           mutate(deal = 0) %>%
           mutate(deal = if_else(row_number(deal) == 1, amount, 0)) %>%
           mutate(deal = cumsum(deal - pmin(capacity, deal)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allocate in two steps:

```
df %>% 
    # allocate cumulatively and truncate if the total surpass the amount
    mutate(allocation = pmin(cumsum(capacity), amount), 
           # calculate the final allocation based on the cumulative allocation
           allocation = allocation - lag(allocation, default = 0))

#  capacity allocation
#1        2          2
#2        3          3
#3        0          0
#4        1          1
#5        2          2
#6        3          2
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option...

```
dfb <- df %>% mutate(allocation=pmin(capacity,
                     pmax(0, amount-lag(cumsum(capacity), default = 0))))

dfb
  capacity allocation
1        2          2
2        3          3
3        0          0
4        1          1
5        2          2
6        3          2
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Psidom's answer, using base R

```
df <- data.frame(capacity = c(2,3,0,1,2,3),
                 allocation = c(0,0,0,0,0,0))
amount <- 10

df$allocation <- diff(pmin(cumsum(c(0, df$capacity)), amount))
```

Result

```
> df
  capacity allocation
1        2          2
2        3          3
3        0          0
4        1          1
5        2          2
6        3          2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
dfb <- df %>% mutate(deal=ifelse(cumsum(capacity)<amount,capacity,capacity+amount-cumsum(capacity)))
```